# How do I "SET ROWCOUNT 1000" in ADO.NET?

Tags: ado.net

I need to make sure my ado.net commands don't return more than 1000-5000 rows.  Is there an ADO.NET way to do this, or is it just a TSQL?

I'm calling a stored procedure, I don't control the source code in that stored procedure.  Hence I was hoping there was a ADO.NET way to do it.

Comment: Are you calling via stored procedure or inline SQL?

Comment: via stored procedure, eg. new SqlCommand("myproc",myconnection)

Answer (score 4):

Before LINQ this typically was always done using a top N clause in your inline query or stored proc. With LINQ there is some cool functions called ["Take" and "Skip"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx) which provides a construct for downloading and or skipping N number of rows. Under the hood LINQ figures out the details of how to construct the inline query that yields the exact number of rows you want off the top.

**[Edit]**

Since you're calling a stored procedure, I'd advise just using a TOP N clause in the select statement. This is path of least resistance and IMHO is the simplest to maintain going forward since you already have the stored procedure.